# Simulating mosfet with body bias ltspice

Tags: mosfet, ltspice

I am trying to simulate a simple mosfet circuit with body bias. I am using the command

```
.model NMOS NMOS (kp=100u Vt0=0.8 phi=0.7 gamma=0.4 )
```

to set up the parameters and I have set the body bias to 3 using a voltage source.
The new Vth calculated by spice is 4.65e-01V but the one I calculated theoretically is  1.23V. What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you set the body voltage of an NMOS transistor to 3V, with the source at ground, then you forward biased the body-source junction. I doubt that SPICE really can model that situation correctly. You probably should not be using more than about 0.5V of voltage from source to body.

On the other hand, how did you calculate the threshold voltage with and without back bias?